# jQuery mouse events don't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a really strange problem. My example code works [here][1] quite fine, but I have the exactly same code in my aptana studio editor and when I try it in Chrome or the Eclipse browser the events just don't fire. I can't imagine what's the problem, because it's exactly the same code ...

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OrderScreen</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
                <a href="">Test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

***jQuery***

```
$("a").mouseup(function() {
    clearTimeout(pressTimer);
    // Clear timeout
    return false;
}).mousedown(function() {
    // Set timeout
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("hcbdhaf")
    }, 1000);
    return false;
}).click(function() {
    alert("dfsdg");
});
```

Comment: is your above events in `$(document).ready(function(){});` ??

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6sWVX/1/

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Yes. Note that the OP's link in the second sentence is also a link to jsFiddle. Yours works for the same reason his/hers does: jsFiddle's default settings hide this particular mistake.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually included the ready event, not that it really matters. I didn't notice his link above.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Wow. And I even looked first. :-) *sigh* (Let's clean up thise comments, they don't add anything. This comment will self-destruct in...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code is really as quoted, the problem is that the elements don't exist as of when you try to hook event handlers to them. jsFiddle's default settings hide this problem from you. (Look on the left, and you'll see that your code isn't run until the `load` event fires — which is very, very late in the page load process.)

To fix it, either:

1. Move your script tags to the end of your document, just before or after the closing `</body>` tag. By the time the browser runs your script, the elements will exist. This is the [recommendation of the YUI team](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and Google's web engineers [like it too](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41).
2. Use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) event.

In conjunction with either of those, you might also look at using event delegation instead of directly hooking up events on the elements. Your `mouseup` and `mousedown` handlers will get attached to *each* `a` element individually. That's a lot of hookups. If there's a container that all of those `a` elements are in (`body` or better yet, something nearer), you might instead hook the event on that container (since those events bubble) and then check to see if the event originated in an `a` element. jQuery supports event delegation, doing most of the hard work for you, via [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) (which I like because it's so explicit) and more recently, one of the half-dozen variations of arguments you pass to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: `$(function() {...})` Sorry, I'm addicted to the shorthand

Comment: @KyleMacey. Was the answer edited? I can't understand your comment at all.

Comment: @gdoron: He's referring to my mentioning the `ready` event. He prefers the shorthand for it, which is to pass a function into the `jQuery` (`$`) function.

Comment: seems preemptive as you didn't even list the function itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Actually, `$(fn)` is calling the `ready` function under the hood not the other way around. And one of the jQuery team suggests to use the `$(document).ready(fn)` so... and anyway, it doesn't matter!

Comment: @gdoron: I didn't say it didn't. "Shorthand" means "shorter way of writing," not "more direct call."

Comment: @user1011185: No worries, glad that helped. (But please don't swear on SO.)

Comment: It wasn't mentioned, just throwing in my two bits